# How to PULL multiple value from a list in a document in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I am currently learning mongoDB, and saw this feature you can use `$each` with `$push` to push multiple values into the database. Here's exact command I used:

```
`bookstore> db.books.updateOne({_id: ObjectId("63e099a98816e61af42af7ad")}, {$push: {genres: {$each: ["1", "2"]}}})`
```

Now I was wondering if the opposite if this command was possible, so replaced $push with $pull and go this error:

```
db.books.updateOne({_id: ObjectId("63e099a98816e61af42af7ad")}, {$pull: {genres: {$each: ["1", "2"]}}})

MongoServerError: unknown top level operator: $each. If you have a field name that starts with a '$' symbol, consider using $getField or $setField.
```

I did try using $get and it yielded another error. Does anyone know how to do this? Many thanks in advance! (I know I can PULL one by one, but I want to explore features which make the day a little bit easier)

update: I tried directly using $pull on the elements. The resultant was this.

```
bookstore> db.books.updateOne({_id: ObjectId("63e099a98816e61af42af7ad")}, {$pull: {genres: ["1", "2"]}})
```

{
acknowledged: true,
insertedId: null,
matchedCount: 1,
modifiedCount: 0,
upsertedCount: 0
}

even though the code didn't give an error, and it did match with a value, the modifiedCount is still 0.

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/operator/update/pullAll/

Comment: thank you @Noel this article helped.
the correct command is:
db.books.updateOne({_id: ObjectId("63e099a98816e61af42af7ad")}, {$pullAll: { genres: ["1", "2"]}})
I don't know how to mark your answer as the correct answer, but it is.